# java how to avoid duplicate in recursion

Tags: java, recursion

i'm trying to search synonym(which i declare as 'synset') recursively. Unfortunately, there are duplicate of synonym. For example: when i search the word student, the output will be like this:

```
Search word: student

Synset 0: pupil
  Synset 0: student
    Synset 0: pupil
    .
    .
    .
  Synset 1: educatee
  Synset 2: schoolchild
Synset 1: educatee
Synset 2: scholar
Synset 3: bookman
```

I want to store all the output into database and I do not need the duplicate output.This is part of my code that consist recursive function. Hope anyone can help me..Thanks

```
public String printSynset(String word)
    {
        //call wordnet library

        RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
        //call stemmer method
        PorterStemmer s = new PorterStemmer();
```

`Vector<String> synsetVec = new Vector<String>();
    String[] synset = wordnet.getAllSynsets(word, "n");

    for (int k=0; k<synset.length; k++)
    {
        synsetVec.add(synset[k]);

        if (!synsetVec.isEmpty())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < synsetVec.size();) 
            {   
                GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");
                GUIsynonymTA.append("   No." + j + ": " + (s.Stem(synsetVec.get(j))));
                GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");

                return printSynset(synsetVec.get(j));
            }
        }

        else if (synsetVec.isEmpty())
            return word;

    }
    return word;
}//end printSynset()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958566/remove-duplicate-chars-from-a-string-recursively

Comment: @Divyesh I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: On a side note, there is no point in doing an `if (!sysnsetVec.isEmpty())` and then an `else if (sysncVec.isEmpty())`. If the `if` returns false you can just do an `else`.

Answer (score 7):

You should maintain a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of the items you've already seen. Every time you hit an item, first check whether it's been seen before; if it is, stop the recursion; if it's not, add it to the set and proceed.

The result is the classic depth-first search for general graphs, which you can find in any algorithms textbook or in [Russell & Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) chapter 3. Pseudocode:

```
Set<Node> printSynset(Node root) {
    HashSet<Node> closed;
    printDFS(root, closed);
}

// recursive graph dfs
void printDFS(Node n, Set<Node> closed) {
    if (!closed.contains(n)) {
        print(n.item);
        closed.add(n);
        for (Node s : n.neighbors())
            printDFS(n, closed);
    }
}
```

Note that when `printDFS` returns to `printSynset`, it will have filled `closed` with all nodes it has visited, so you could also choose to return that `Set<Node>` and loop over it in `printSynset`, instead of doing the printing in `printDFS`. That would leave you with a general, re-usable DFS routine.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans. Actually this is what i'm trying to do. Using depth-first search to get the results. Just because i do not know how to implement it here, i'm tring to use recursion.

Comment: recursion is fine for depth-first search. You just need to be 100% sure that your recursion will not happen for every step because then you have infinite looping which for recursion results in stackoverflow

Comment: @syakirahibrahim: added pseudocode for a recursive DFS printing routine.

Comment: Does this mean that the Set is a global variable(in Java) ? I can't imagine how a recursive function can pass the Set through the recursion chain by value and maintain consistency.

Answer (score 4):

Use a Set to store the previously found matches. If the word is in the Set don't output it again.

[Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Maintain the Set as a class level field so that all the recursions of the method have access to the Set. If `Set.add(word)` returns `false` you know that the word was already in the `Set`.