# Avoiding duplicates in pass-by-value recursive methods: requires outside variables?

Tags: java, recursion, memoization

When writing a recursive function in Java and attempting to avoid duplicate recursions/outcomes, I've read that you need to include a [Set that keeps track of what computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611587/java-how-to-avoid-duplicate-in-recursion) has already been done. It seems you cannot keep the Set inside the scope of a recursive function, as Java (pass-by-value) will pass down different versions of the Set along each different branch.

Does such a Set have to be created outside the method?

Answer (score 0):

In Short : Yes, it needs to be in a broader scope than the recursive function.

However, since we're tracking the computations, at any rate, why not take a dynamic programming approach for the memoization? In this case, you can avoid recursion altogether.

Comment: Actually, I think in this case, the whole tree will use the same Set object because Java makes sure objects persist as they pass through methods. For example, a change to an element of an ArrayList (that has been passed as an argument) in a method is observable outside of the method scope after the method is completed.